# Is there a standard drawing tool used for asking or answering questions?

Tags: support, images

[MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/137035) is a very useful tool to express many mathematical expressions. It is a fundamental part of asking or answering questions. Sometimes, I would like to visualize things to make them more explicit when asking or answering questions. However, I don't know an easy tool, so I don't usually bother with drawing.

Is there an equivalent tool of MathJax when drawing lines, circles, 3D objects etc.? If not, what do you do?

Comment: You can find several related question here. For example:
[Creating diagrams](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/creating-diagrams), 
[Is there a way to draw a graph (vertices & edges) in LaTeX on this website?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11049), [How could I add a graph to a post at MSE?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9435/how-could-i-add-a-graph-to-a-post-at-mse),
[Software for drawing geometry diagrams](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985),
[Looking for a Drawing Program](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105754).

Comment: @MartinSleziak As far as I understand, Tikz package is mostly preferred. But there is no native support so we have to create a png file and upload it. Since the subject is much broader, it may not be possible to create a Tikz tutorial like the MathJax tutorial above. It seems we are on our own when it comes to drawing.

Comment: There must be hundreds of tikz tutorials out there, not to mention the inkscape tutorials.

Comment: I've never used a Tikz based illustration, but Community ads for [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) and [GeoGebra](https://web.geogebra.org/app/) induced me to try both for graphs.  Some desktop image/drawing packages produce formats that are not immediately usable by StackExchange, so websites that do format conversions are another part of my toolkit.