# Software to draw Geometrical Diagrams

Tags: discussion, images

On MSE, many users include diagrams with their solutions to help illustrate concepts and make their solutions clearer. Is there an optimal software for doing so? Any recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: See, for example: [Creating diagrams](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9632) and [Is there a standard drawing tool used for asking or answering questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21386) (And the links which are given there - including some links to related questions on the main site.)

Comment: It would improve your Question to be more specific about what you mean by "geometrical" diagrams.  There are many kinds of illustrations, ranging from geometric figures (2- and 3-dimensional) to the lattice-like formulas of category theory, that one might want to include.  Naturally better recommendations can be made for a specific sort of diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Geometer's Sketchpad®** might be helpful.
[The Geometer's Sketchpad® (Software)](https://www.mheducation.com/prek-12/program/geometer-s-sketchpad-software2012/MKTSP-HGA01M0.html?page=1&sortby=title&order=asc&bu=seg)

[image]

Here is a demonstration video [Geometer's Sketchpad: Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqjWBeR_nqQ)

It is targeted to grade levels 3 to 12, I suppose it would meet the need of the most users unless you want something more high-end.

You do need to purchase a license to use the complete edition. However, they do offer a demo to try out with. [Trial Version](http://info.mheducation.com/sketchpad.trial.html)

Comment: Welcome to Meta Math.SE.  It would improve your Answer to include experience with suitability of this proprietary software for the task of adding images to posts on Math.SE.  Licensing per computer and targeting to grade levels 3 to 12 would seem significant limitations, perhaps offset by significant features.  If you don't have such first-hand knowledge, then a brief response as above would ordinarily be better given as a Comment.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but my reputation is not high enough to leave comment everywhere yet. I will try my best to implement my answer.

Comment: Thanks nonetheless. I will try it out

Answer (score 2):

You may want to see [math3d.org](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29693/290189), the 3D analogue if Desmos.  It has intuitive user interface and 3D graphing support.